# Adding to list repopulates with the last element

Tags: c#

I'm creating a list of objects called MyComposedModel.

```
List<MyComposedModel> TheListOfModel = new List<MyComposedModel>();
MyComposedModel ThisObject = new MyComposedModel();

foreach (MyComposedModel in some list of MyComposedModel)
{
 ThisObject.Reset(); //clears all properties
 ....
 TheListOfModel.Add(ThisObject);
}
```

The problem is that each time the for-each loop iterates and executes the .Add statement, the list is repopulated with n+1 objects and every object in the list is ThisObject. So for instance, the second time it runs, the last item is correctly inserted in position [1] BUT the first item in [0] is replaced with the second item and the list contains the second item in both positions.

ThisObject has a property called ID and when I debug, I see the ID change so I know that it's going through the list but when it reaches the .Add line, I don't know what happens.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? You say the behavior is incorrect but not what the correct one should be.

Comment: each time is iterates, it should keep the previous elements of the list and add the new one instead of replacing every element with the new one.

Comment: Please mention the name of the loop variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have only 1 object...

`MyComposedModel` is a reference type. You are filling a list with references to the same single object, and only the last properties stand.

What you probably need:

```
foreach (MyComposedModel otherObject in some list)
{
 //ThisObject.Reset();                  // clears all properties
   thisObject = new MyComposedModel();  // create a new instance instead
  ....
  TheListOfModel.Add(thisObject);
}
```

Comment: But that's going to create n instances of the object. I just want one object, clear it each time, and add the values of each iteration to the list.

Comment: @frenchie: and where are those values going to be kept?

Comment: ok, I got it, thanks for your suggestion. If I want to create a list of n objects, I need to create n objects:) Got it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're incorrectly re-using a reference to the same object over and over.

When you do this:

```
MyComposedModel ThisObject = new MyComposedModel();
```

That create a single reference to a new object and places it on the stack. When you iterate your list and do this:

```
ThisObject.Reset(); //clears all properties
```

It's still pointing to the SAME reference, you need to just create a new object of type "MyComposedModel", set it's properties and add it to the list.

Comment: but why is the first element wiped out?

Comment: @frenchie because you're modifying the same block of memory every iteration. Every item in your list is going to be identical to the "last" one added. You essentially have a 1 element list of N identical items.